# How can I paste multiple rows in LyX?

Tags: lyx

I would like to paste multiple rows at the same time in LyX. The following animation shows how all data is pasted into a singular cell instead of multiple cells across multiple rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cursor in the first cell and press <kbd>ctrl + shift + v</kbd>, or do Edit > Paste Special > Plain Text. See [here](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/7932) for a related bug report.